# What formats of music/sound are good for Unity3D games?

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

I am new to Unity 3D. And we are developing a mobile game in Unity 3D. Some of our *.wav sound files are relatively large, say 25MB for a level background music. And we are going to have different music for different levels. And the size could be a problem, consider most of the mobile game sizes are under 200MB.

So what formats are the best for Unity 3D games? which has a nice balance in size and sound quality? Is there any general guidelines of how to compress the music, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/what-the-best-audio-format-for-games.36943/ 2009 though so this could be outdated.

Comment: thanks @nicovank, I am afraid it is outdated, this is 8 years ago...

Comment: I always use .ogg

Comment: you can use audacity to convert wavs to ogg, its free! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an outdated question, yes, but Unity supports a wide range of audio files. Including:
.mp3
.ogg
.wav
.aiff

and more. I prefer either .mp3 or .oog because of their small file size.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use OGG which I feel is a good compromise between small file sizes and good quality.

As far as I know and understand, Unity re-encodes your source files anyway. Therefore your question about your assets' original format may be not as relevant as you might expect, concerning the data format in the published game binaries. See also [manual on Audio](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AudioFiles.html).

You may influence what is actually stored and distributed by changing the Import Settings for each audio asset file.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some devices that could have issues with mp3 files has they haven't the mp3 chip decoder so the best option it's ogg files, also ogg usually compress better.